# Draw a line in iPhone , Exception

Tags: iphone, exception, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

Im trying to draw a line.

I wrote a code like below.

```
UIColor *currentColor = [UIColor blackColor];

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,endingPoint.x , endingPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

but this shows exception as follows

```
Sat Aug 21 10:47:20 AAA-rrr-Mac-mini.local Test[2147] <Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
Sat Aug 21 10:47:20 AAA-rrr-Mac-mini.local Test[2147] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Sat Aug 21 10:47:20 AAA-rrr-Mac-mini.local Test[2147] <Error>: CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Sat Aug 21 10:47:20 AAA-rrr-Mac-mini.local Test[2147] <Error>: CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0
Sat Aug 21 10:47:20 AAA-rrr-Mac-mini.local Test[2147] <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
```

Comment: You don't actually have a graphics context. Are you doing this inside a drawRect: or some other random place?

Comment: im using it in my own function named drawLine:(CGPoint )From:(CGPoint )To

Comment: should include any framework or some file for drawing?

Comment: you should always use `drawRect:` for drawing and use `setNeedsDisplay` for any refresh you wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to call `CGContextBeginPath(ctx);` just before you call `CGContextMoveToPoint`

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
  UIColor *currentColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
  CGContextBeginPath(context); // <---- this 
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.x, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.y);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: You also need to use `CGContextClosePath`

Answer (score 2):

You have no valid graphics context. `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` obviously returned `nil`.

Where do you want to draw to?

If you want to draw to the screen, then you should implement the `drawRect:` method of `UIView` or one of its subclasses and have iOS call that method (by triggering a refresh of part of your screen). Then you will have a valid graphics context during the execution of `drawRect:`.

If you want to draw to an offscreen pixel map, then you have to create a graphics context yourself with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` or a similar function.

**EDIT:**

So for drawing into a *UIView*, you need to create a *UIView* subclass and override *drawRect:*

```
@interfaceMyView : UIView {
}

@end


@implementation MyUIView

- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
  UIColor *currentColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, currentColor.CGColor);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.x, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.y);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Then you open the XIB file (that you probably already have= in Interface Builder, add a *UIView* there and select MyUIView as the class (first field on the last tab in the Inspector window).

Comment: Can you give a small example.

Comment: I can give you an example if you answer where you want to draw to.

Comment: I want to draw a line in UIView